# Edit SQLite3 database information

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, ef-power-tools

In VS2019 I have window opened "SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox". If I right-click on my SQLite3 db there one of menu items says "Database Information". If I run that I get:

```
-- Script Date: 12/12/2020 12:19  - ErikEJ.SqlCeScripting version 3.5.2.86
-- Database information:
-- Database: C:\Dev\WrongProjectPath\app.db
-- ServerVersion: 3.30.1
-- DatabaseSize: 176 KB
-- Created: 18/11/2020 18:38

-- User Table information:

. . .
```

I also can see `WrongProjectPath` in the actual db file with HEX editor.

I copied this db from another project and now would like to change that information to reflect correct project name.

How can I do that?

Comment: Remove the connection from the Toolbox, and point to the correct path when adding a new connection

Answer (score 0):

*(answering for @ErikEJ)*

Remove the connection from the Toolbox, and point to the correct path when adding a new connection